# How to change the color of Emacs comments in C++/C mode to light pink

Tags: emacs

While in C++/C mode, Emacs 23 colors source code comments in bold red. Strings literals are colored in light pink.

I would like to switch these colors (comments in light pink and string literals in red) because I find the comments become an eye-sore in heavily commented programs..

How do I do this? I don't want to install a new color scheme since I am already very happy with the default one in other respects.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs file:

```
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-string-face "red")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "light pink")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. On a side note, is it possible to specify RGB values within the code you have pasted so that I can customize the colors a bit more?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: Of course you can (this is emacs eh ;)) Just use "#ff0000" instead of "red" for example. `M-x list-colors-display` is also very nice.

Answer (score 16):

To do this interactively, place your point on a comment or string and run <kbd>M-x customize-face</kbd> and select the color you'd like.